# Como executar um virtual environment do python na crontab do linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, virtualenv

criei um virtual environment:

```
python -m venv test
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

E criei um scrip `C:\fnord\Documents\Scripts_python\test\Scripts\test.py`

Então, como devo proceder para criar o agendamento, como por exemplo:

```
30 08 10 06 * python C:\fnord\Documents\Scripts_python\test\Scripts\test.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar o caminho completo para o python instalado no virtualenv.

```
30 08 10 06 * /home/venv/bin/python3 /<caminho_do_script>/Scripts/test.py
```

Você pode também criar um script .sh que ative o virtual environment e depois chame seu script python. Isso ajuda quanto tiver várias ações a serem executadas.

Comment: (opa Rodrigo - eu mudei um pouco a frase ali só pra ficar bem claro mesmo - mas valeu pela resposta rápida e correta)